# quarkusio change default debug port using quarkus:dev

Tags: quarkus

I have two apps running.

App1: Read from amq, enrich the message and send the message to App2 through other amq

App2: Read the message and call another project for processing.

Y want to debug booth Apps in the same time and see how the message change in time.

When I start the App2 with **mvn compile quarkus:dev** I got this:

**[ERROR] Port 5005 in use, not starting in debug mode**

of course the app is runnig but without debuger.

Exist some way to change the default debug port in quarkus?

PD: I just try -Dquarkus.debug.port=5006, but nothing happens...

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `-Ddebug` system property can be used to specify a debug port as well. In your case, `mvn compile quarkus:dev -Ddebug=5006` should work.

See this javadoc https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/1.8.1.Final/devtools/maven/src/main/java/io/quarkus/maven/DevMojo.java#L140-L166 for more info.

Comment: If you expose an HTTP endpoint, you'll also get an error that port 8080 is already taken. To fix both use `mvn quarkus:dev -Ddebug=5006 -Dquarkus.http.port=8081`

Answer (score 5):

## Add a configuration on quarkus-maven-plugin.

1 Go to your pom;

2 Find the plugin tag;

3 Add configuration tag pair;

4 Add debug tag pair;

5 Insert the port you want on step 4;

6 Start your application and check the logs. You are good to go.

Example:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
    <configuration>
      <debug>6006</debug>
    </configuration>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>build</goal>
          <goal>generate-code</goal>
          <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
```

[image: Debugging on wanted port log]

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the process running on that port & kill it manually. Below are the commands to do it in the Windows OS using PowerShell:

```
> Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 8080).OwningProcess 
> taskkill /f /PID <pid-got-from-above-command>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using Gradle, you can set the debug port in each application's `build.gradle`, like this:

```
quarkusDev {
    doFirst {
        System.setProperty("debug", "5101") // APP1 debug port
    }
}
```